# How to logically compare values (numbers) field values in CakePHP 3 validation

Tags: php, validation, cakephp, cakephp-3.0, comparison-operators

I'm trying to use the [comparison rule](http://api.cakephp.org/3.1/source-class-Cake.Validation.Validation.html#_comparison) but seems am missing something or not doing it right. Basically what I need is validation to check that the value of **small_size** is less or equal to **big_size**.

But this isn't working, am currently getting the error regardless of the sizes.

In the **Table**:

```
     ...
     $validator
        ->add('small_size', 'valid', ['rule' => 'numeric'])
        ->requirePresence('small_size', 'create')
        ->notEmpty('small_size')
        ->add('small_size', 'comparison', [
            'rule' => ['comparison', 'big_size', '<='],
            'message' => 'Small size cannot be more than the Big size.'
        ]);
    return $validator;
}

public function buildRules(RulesChecker $rules)
{
    $rules->add($rules->existsIn(['Entity_id'], 'Entity'));
    return $rules;
}
```

Some help on this will be much appreciated.

Comment: as answered by @Holt, u need to see custom validations: http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/validation.html#conditional-validation

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot use the built-in [`comparison`](http://api.cakephp.org/3.0/class-Cake.Validation.Validation.html#_comparison) rule to compare two fields, you need to use a [custom rule](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/validation.html#custom-validation-rules):

```
$validator->add('small_size', 'comparison', [
    'rule' => function ($value, $context) {
        return intval($value) <= intval($context['data']['big_size']) ;
    },
    'message' => 'Small size cannot be bigger than Big size.'
]);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  In this case what is $value? Or where is it coming from?

Comment: This is the standards rule form specified by cake: `$value` is the value of the targeted field while `$context` contains the validation context (and thus all the data).

Answer (score 2):

You can use the compareFields method to compare two fields
https://api.cakephp.org/3.6/class-Cake.Validation.Validation.html#_compareFields

like:

```
->add('small_size', 'compareFields', [
        'rule' => ['compareFields', 'small_size','big_siz', '<='],
        'message' => 'Small size cannot be bigger than Big size.'
    ]);
```